# Agenda scheduled job running only once

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scheduled-tasks

I have a sample program to start working with Agenda, and it gets stuck after running the first time.

```
 var Agenda = require('agenda');

 var agenda = new Agenda({db: {address: 'localhost/sample-dev', collection: 'pollingJob'}});

agenda.define('First1', function(job, done) {
  var d = new Date();
  console.log("Hello First Job at " + d );
});

agenda.on('ready', function() {
  agenda.every('5 seconds', 'First1');
  agenda.start();
});
```

I have done it all as per the instructions on [Agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda), am I missing something out here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the **[docs](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda#definejobname-options-fn)**,

> When a job of job name gets run, it will be passed to fn(job, done).
>   To maintain asynchronous behavior, you must call done() when you are
>   processing the job. If your function is synchronous, you may omit done
>   from the signature.

So, from the above omit the callback and re-define the basic example as a synchronous job, like the following:

```
agenda.define('First1', function(job) {
    var d = new Date();
    console.log("Hello First Job at " + d );
});

agenda.on('ready', function() {
    agenda.every('5 seconds', 'First1');
    agenda.start();
});
```

Comment: Thanks Chridam! I didn't realise this part.

Comment: @swateek No worries, happy to help :)